# How to change the user timezone?

Tags: ssh, non-root-user, timezone

I know that (for example in Debian) one could use `dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` to change the timezone of the **system** but I am wondering how one could change the **user** timezone (if Linux/Unix supports such an idea at all).

I normally work on the server remotely through ssh and given that the server works with UTC internally (files, ...) and timezones are rather superficial, I would like to see the times in my desired timezone depending on where I am connecting from. Is this possible?

Comment: What did you try? Did you even search for "ssh passing on TZ information" on the web at all?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use the `TZ` environment variable.  E.g.:

```
bash$ export TZ=US/Pacific
bash$ date
Mon Mar  3 00:31:17 PST 2014
bash$ export TZ=US/Eastern
bash$ date
Mon Mar  3 03:33:06 EST 2014
```

The possible values for `TZ` are in the directory `/usr/share/zoneinfo` (see, for example, the existence of `/usr/share/zoneinfo/US/Pacific`)

Comment: In my case, `date` gives a different time-zose and time than `uname -a`. Why would that be?

Comment: `uname` doesn't list the current timezone or anything regarding time. If you run `uname -v`, that will print the version of the kernel currently running which might include a timestamp listing when the kernel was built. That's a static piece of text that is not affected by your `TZ` setting.

Answer (score 9):

First, you need some configs for ssh server and ssh client.

In Server, in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, make sure you accept `TZ` variable:

```
AcceptEnv LANG LC_* TZ
```

In Client, in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` or `~/.ssh/config`, make sure you send `TZ` variable:

```
SendEnv TZ
```

(The defaults are usually to send none from the client, and accept none on the server.)

Then make alias for `ssh` command to use your current `TZ` in `ssh` session. Add this line to `.bashrc` file:

```
alias ssh='TZ=${TZ:-"$(cat /etc/timezone)"} ssh'
```

or use this for system doesn't have `/etc/timezone`:

```
alias ssh='TZ=${TZ:-"$(date +%Z)"} ssh'
```

Then every time you `ssh` to remote server, the time on server will display base on you local timezone.

Comment: You can also use `TZ=$(date +%Z)` with most versions (Linux/*BSD/Solaris) of date, this will work better on systems where `/etc/timezone` isn't the done thing.

Comment: Friendly reminder. Remember to restart sshd for changes to take effect. On ubuntu "service ssh restart"